How to pronounce Proto-Indo-European words?
I want to know how do I get to know how to pronounce proto-Indo-European words from how they are spelled currently?
I do understand that the exact pronunciation is not certain for many words, but it must be the case that one pronunciation (or at least a group of pronunciations) for each word is considered the most plausible. Where can I get those pronunciations?
I have read this question and the answer to it (hence, the previous paragraph). I do not need a definite IPA representation for each word (for words where this is possible, this might be great though!), but even descriptions on what might be some good candidates for any given word would be helpful.
And if not a word by word source, is there a source where enough of the general patterns (as mentioned in the answer to the question mentioned above) are written in a way that I can attempt thinking of a plausible pronunciation of a word myself?
Clarification: I am not asking for exact IPA pronunciations for each word. Best guesses, or even a rough set of instructions that allows me to try to form guesses myself would also help me. If there is a word "xyz", it must be the case that linguists feel some pronunciations are more likely than others, even though they cannot be sure. I want a way to replicate the guesses made by the linguists roughly, if I do not have those guesses in the first place.

I would normally close this as a duplicate, but you've linked to the question it's a duplicate of. What are you looking for that's not found there?

Unlike modern languages, where we can simply listen to native speakers and describe the sounds they use in detail, the very nature of reconstructed proto-languages means that we can say very, very little about how things actually sounded. We can make educated guesses at what sound values specific morphophonemic units had, which is what the answer to the linked question does, but we can do little more. Once you’ve decided which sound you want to associate with each reconstructed unit, an ‘IPA’ representation is a simple matter of substitution – so what exactly are you looking for here?

Hi, thanks for the comments! I am looking for some source that has (in the best case scenario) a list of best guesses for how each word is pronounced, sort of like a dictionary with phonetic information attached to each word. Otherwise, a generic list of instructions on how I can myself try to deduce possible pronunciations for a substantial number of words might also help, so that i can try to construct something like that dictionary myself for my use

in that case this seems to me to be an exact duplicate of the other question

Does this answer your question? Proto-Indo-European (PIE) words with IPA

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
